# use folder yolov5 when put it in other subfolder and avoid "no module name yolov5"

Tags: python, import, directory, yolov5

I have a problem when load model.pt use torch.hub.load. If I do not put yolov5 folder in any subfolder, it's OK. but when I put it into subfolder such as lib folder, I get error " no module name yolov5" when I load model:

```
torch.hub.load(WEIGHTS/'lib'/'yolov5','custom',path=WEIGHTS/'yolov5s.pt',source='local')
```

WEIGHTS is the current path of my project
I see that for example, if I change import line in `hubconf.py`

```
from yolov5.models.common import AutoShape, DetectMultiBackend
```

to

```
from lib.yolov5.models.common import AutoShape, DetectMultiBackend
```

, it will not error at here. But there is so so much line import code from yolov5_folder like hubconf.py above. Is there any way do not need change import line into `from lib....`
My folder structure is:\

```
Project_folder -> WEIGHT is path of this\
------code.py -> torch.hub.load in here\
------lib_folder\
---------yolov5_folder \
```

Yolov5 folder I clone from github of ultralytics

How I can fix the error " no module name yolov5" that do not need convert to  `from lib.` when I put yolov5 in other subfolder?
Thank you so much